# Replacing text between two limts

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to get the text between two symbols to be replaced with `preg_replace`, but alas still not quite getting it right as I get a null output that is empty string, this is what I have so far

```
$start = '["';
$end   = '"]';
$msg   = preg_replace('#('.$start.')(.*)('.$end.')#si', '$1 test $3', $row['body']);
```

So an example output I am looking for would be:

```
normal text [everythingheregone] after text
```

To

```
 normal text [test] after text
```

Comment: Is normal text and after text always constant?

Comment: The `$start` and `$end` anchors must be strings, and it must be escaped. You're using an array, and `[` will be a problem.

Comment: @Bhushan no the text before and after will be changing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are defining $start and $end as arrays, but using it as normal variables. Try changing your code to this:

```
$start = '\[';
$end  = '\]';
$msg = preg_replace('#('.$start.')(.*)('.$end.')#si', '$1 test $3', $row['body']);
```

Comment: Which character in your regex pattern are you making case-insensitive with that `i` modifier?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$str  = "normal text [everythingheregone] after text";
$repl = "test";
$patt = "/\[([^\]]+)\]/"; 
$res  = preg_replace($patt, "[". $repl ."]", $str);
```

Should yield `normal text [test] after text`

**EDIT**

Fiddle demo [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/sdk-u6g)

Comment: this gives a blank output as well

Answer (score 1):

some functions that may help

```
function getBetweenStr($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);    
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
    }
```

and

```
function getAllBetweenStr($string, $start, $end)
    {
        preg_match_all( '/' . preg_quote( $start, '/') . '(.*?)' . preg_quote( $end, '/') . '/', $string, $matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row['body']= "normal text [everythingheregone] after text ";
$start = '\[';
$end = '\]';
$msg = preg_replace('#'.$start.'.*?'.$end.'#s', '$1 [test] $3', $row['body']);
//output: normal text [test] after text done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a regex approach. The regular expression is :`\[.*?]`

```
<?php
$string = 'normal text [everythingheregone] after text ';
$pattern = '\[.*?]';
$replacement = '[test]'
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
//normal text [test] after text
?>
```