# PHP replace string between

Tags: php

I have the following string:

```
$string = '<img id="Afbeelding_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01D0D37B.5E4E6AE0" alt="logo" height="39" border="0" width="125">';
```

And I want to replace everything between `src="cid:` and `"` to a normal img url, so it becomes like this:

```
$string = '<img id="Afbeelding_x0020_1" src="image.png" alt="logo" height="39" border="0" width="125">';
```

Everything before and after has to be preserved because it's a whole message, so it's also important to replace only between `src="cid:REPLACE@ID"`

I have tried this but this does nothing:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id='".$ticketID."'";
            $con = $GLOBALS['db_con']->query($query);
            $rd = $con->fetch_assoc();
            if(strpos($rd['message'],'src="cid:') !== false){ $bodyImage = extract_unit($rd['message'], 'src="cid:', '@'); }
            $imgUrl = 'src="' . $GLOBALS['site_info']['url'] . '/tickets/' . $ticketID . '/' . $bodyImage . '"';
            $start = '\src="cid:';
            $end  = '\"';
            $result = preg_replace('#('.$start.')(.*)('.$end.')#si', $imgUrl, $rd['message']);
            return $result;
```

I have this code from: [Replacing text between two limts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832239/replacing-text-between-two-limts)

The `$imgUrl` is being build up correcly but `preg_replace()` isn't doing anything.

Anyone who knows a solution? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: here `\src` slash s  is space. write `src=...`

Comment: if you are dealing with HTML/XML data, what about using an DOM parser..?

Comment: @JuniusRendel This is no XML data, pure HTML

Comment: However, resources for DOM parsing/modification are legions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using this code:

```
function replace_ticketImage($msg,$ticketID,$replyID){
    if(strpos($msg,'src="cid:') !== false){
        $bodyString = extract_unit($msg, 'src="cid:', '"');
        $bodyImage = extract_unit($msg, 'src="cid:', '@');
        if($replyID < 1){
            $imgUrl = $GLOBALS['site_info']['url'] . '/attachments/tickets/' . $ticketID . '/' . $bodyImage;
        } else {
            $imgUrl = $GLOBALS['site_info']['url'] . '/attachments/tickets/' . $ticketID . '/' . $replyID . '/' . $bodyImage;
        }
        $result = preg_replace('/cid:'.$bodyString.'/', $imgUrl, $msg);
    } else {
        $result = $msg;
    }
    return $result;
}
```