# String Replace in php not working as expected

Tags: php

I have a String as follows:

```
$var = "Hello Hi World it is an awesome day. Test Hi guys Whats up";
```

I am trying to replace the value in my string as follows:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
        } 

$parsed0 = get_string_between($var, "Hello", "World");

So I get the String in `$parse0`
```

And I am replacing as follows:

```
$varnew = str_replace($parsed0,"NEWVALUE", $var);

echo $varnew;
```

I get output as follows:

```
Hello NEWVALUE World it is an awesome day. Test NEWVALUE guys Whats up
```

My expected result is:

```
Hello NEWVALUE World it is an awesome day. Test Hi guys Whats up.
```

This is happening because in `$parse0` I get result as `Hi` and it contains two times in that String.

Is there any way I get start and and end positions using a function and replace it using those?

Comment: @Justcode in my case I need may have very big String may contain more repetitions. I know the first and end string and need to put in between. Please guide me!!

Comment: @Justcode it is replacing the first or second occurrence and so on.  In my case I need replace the value between two strings. hope you get it now!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832239/replacing-text-between-two-limts does this help?

Comment: this previously answered link might be helpful-

http://stackoverflow.com/a/9598725/5315670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Check the code below.

```
function customReplace($string, $start, $end, $value = "NEWVALUE"){
    return preg_replace_callback('/'.$start.'(.*?)'.$end.'/', function($m) use($start, $end){
        return "$start NEWVALUE $end";
    }, $string);
}

$var = "Hello Hi World it is an awesome day. Test Hi guys Whats up";

echo customReplace($var, "Hello", "World");
```

Output:

```
Hello NEWVALUE World it is an awesome day. Test Hi guys Whats up
```

Problem with your code is:

```
$varnew = str_replace($parsed0,"NEWVALUE", $var);
```

`$parsed0` has `Hi` (which you fetched from the function), and saying `str_replace` to replace `Hi` with `NEWVALUE` in the string `$var`(whole string). So `str_replace` is working as expected. Hope it is clear now.

**UPDATE**

Also check @b263 answer below. You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) too, it doesn't require a callback.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello NEWVALUE World it is an awesome day. Test Hi guys Whats up.

You're not going to be able to do that with str_replace.

```
$var = "Hello Hi World it is an awesome day. Test Hi guys Whats up";
//$parsed0 = 'Hi';
$varnew = str_replace($parsed0,"NEWVALUE", $var);
```

Because $parsed0 = 'Hi', any occurrence of 'Hi'in that string is going to be replaced. If you just want to replace the first occurrence, you could do the following

```
$varnew = preg_replace('/'.$parsed0.'/', ' NEWVALUE ', $var, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceBetween($start, $end, $replacement, $subject) {
  return preg_replace("/(${start}\s+).*?(\s+${end})/", "$1${replacement}$2", $subject);
}

$var = 'Hello Hi World it is an awesome day. Test Hi guys Whats up';

echo replaceBetween('Hello', 'World', 'NEWVALUE', $var);
```